# Lotus Note Mail signing using Java API via DIIOP

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, signing, java

We are using DIIOP to send mail in a Java program, but when the recipient open the mail, although there is "This message is digitally signed" , there is a warning message on the status bar "This Document has been altered since the time it was signed! Intentional tampering may have occurred." Checking the properties of the received mail "$Signature" is there, but "$SignatureStatus" is "2" indicating that the document has been alter after being signed.

The code snippet:

```
lotus.domino.Document memo = dominoDb.createDocument();
memo.replaceItemValue( "Form", "Memo" );
...
memo.setSaveMessageOnSend(true);
memo.setSignOnSend(true);
memo.sign();
memo.send(false);
```

If either memo.sign() or memo.setSignOnSend(true) is omitted, the received document would not be signed with no $Signature, and $SignatureStatus of value "0".

By the way, the memo.setEncryptOnSend(boolean) works just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sign email messages using the Notes Java API over DIIOP.

Encryption works because it requires the recipient's public key, which is in the Domino Directory on the server and is accessible to the API code which is remotely accessed on the server via DIIOP.

Digital signature, on the other hand, requires the sender's private key. The private key is stored in the user's Notes ID file. When you're connecting to Notes over DIIOP, you are not prompted for the password for the user's Notes ID file, which would be required in order to access the private key.

In fact, in most cases where you would be using DIIOP, the user's Notes ID file doesn't even exist on the machine where your code is running because there is no installation of Notes software on the machine. All you have is the NCSO.jar file, which does not include the core Notes code that has the ability to decrypt and read the ID file. And although the user's Notes ID file may exist on the server that you are connecting to, where it might be stored in the ID vault, there is no way to access the private key inside it via any published API.

Comment: I could send signed mail from Java via DIIOP using my protocol standalone program.  It's only after integrating with the existing code, then the problem appears. Found that it was caused by the conversion of MIME to richtext on the server side.  Because signing mime mail requires internet cert,we had to set session.convertMIME(true) and create a MIME document, set the "To", "Cc" and "Bcc" headers of the MIMEEntity.  save it and retrieve it again so that it became RIchtext, Then we have the signing problem.  However if we set the "SentTo", "CopyTo", "BlindCopyTo" items, we can sign the document

Comment: How is your standalone code accessing the private key for the internet cert? If you are using DIIOP, your code works without the local Notes DLLs, so it cannot read the user ID file. The private key for the internet cert is in the user ID file. Does your code prompt for the ID file's password? The only way I can imagine that this works over DIIOP is if you've got the ID synched into the user's mail file. DWA (iNotes) can sign messages from a browser using this mechanism, but I didn't think that the DIIOP could do that.

Comment: It's signed by the server, not the user, though. You are correct.

Comment: Okay, yes... That does make sense.